# Kann man »weder noch« so benutzen?

Tags: word-usage, conjunction

Kann man *weder noch* so benutzen?

> Meine Frau hat in Jordanien **weder**  Verwandte  **noch** sind  ihr Lebensunterhalt und Unterkunft  gesichert."

Comment: Ich würde sagen Ja, aber das wäre etwas kurz. Frage: Wieso sollte man es nicht so benutzten können? Woher die Zweifel?

Comment: Ich würde eher `Meine Frau hat in Jordanien weder Verwandte noch sind ihr Lebensunterhalt **oder** ihre Unterkunft gesichert.` verwenden, aber das ist vermutlich Geschmackssache.

Comment: "Ja". Ist aber zu kurz für eine Antwort.

Comment: Ich finde der Satz klingt komisch. (ich kann aber nicht festmachen wieso,  deswegen nur als Comment).  Ich würde sagen "Meine Frau hat in Jordanien keine Verwandten,  keine Unterkunft und ihr Lebensunterhalt ist nicht gesichert"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Satz ist zwar verständlich und könnte auch von einem Muttersprachler so geäußert werden, aber trotzdem ist er stilistisch unschön, weil hier *weder* und *noch* nicht gleichwertig verwendet werden, da sie zu verschiedenen Verben (*hat / sind*) gehören. Besser wären beispielsweise diese Formulierungen:

> - *Meine Frau hat in Jordanien **weder** Verwandte **noch** gesicherte Lebensverhältnisse.*
> - *Meine Frau hat **keine** Verwandten in Jordanien
>
>     **und weder** ihr Lebensunterhalt **noch** ihre Unterkunft sind **dort** gesichert.*
> - *Meine Frau hat in Jordanien **keine** Verwandten
>
>     **und dort** sind **weder** ihr Lebensunterhalt **noch** ihre Unterkunft gesichert.*
> - ***Weder** hat meine Frau Verwandte in Jordanien
>
>     **noch** sind ihr Lebensunterhalt und Unterkunft **dort** gesichert.*

Da sich (vermutlich) beide Aussagen auf Jordanien beziehen, sollte die zweite mit *dort* darauf Bezug nehmen.

Übrigens würde ich mit *weder … noch* den Singular *ist* statt dem Plural *sind* nicht nur akzeptieren, sondern bevorzugen.

> - *Meine Frau hat keine Verwandten in Jordanien
>
>     und weder ihr Lebensunterhalt noch ihre Unterkunft **ist** dort gesichert.*
> - *Meine Frau hat in Jordanien keine Verwandten
>
>     und dort **ist** weder ihr Lebensunterhalt noch ihre Unterkunft gesichert.*

Comment: Genau. Ohne das *dort* habe ich den Satz in der Tat anders (wahrscheinlich falsch) verstanden.

Comment: Laut Duden sind bei „weder … noch“ Singular und Plural des Verbs möglich. Der Plural ist häufiger, wenn das Subjekt dem Verb vorausgeht („weder ihr Lebensunterhalt noch ihre Unterkunft sind dort gesichert“), der Singular dagegen, wenn es ihm folgt („dort ist weder ihr Lebensunterhalt noch ihre Unterkunft gesichert“).

Answer (score 2):

Meiner Meinung nach ist der Satz schon korrekt so. Du drückst aus, dass sie in Jordanien beides nicht hat: Verwandte und gesicherten Lebensunterhalt/Unterkunft.

Ich denke, dass das Gefühl, dass der Satz nicht stimmt, daher rührt, dass man *weder/noch* üblicherweise mit Dingen aus demselben „Bereich“ verwendet. Beispielsweise:

> Ich habe weder Freunde noch Verwandte in Jordanien.
>   Es gab weder Essen noch Trinken.

In Deinem Fall hat man zunächst das Gefühl, dass etwas nicht passt, weil eine Kontextverschiebung stattfindet. Aber es gibt durchaus auch andere Beispiele, wo man das machen kann.

> Der Mann konnte weder laufen, noch wollte er überhaupt nach Hause.
>   Hunde können weder sprechen, noch können Sie selbstständig Auto fahren.